# iframe send data to textbox and click button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, authentication

i want design login page but code doesn't work 
have problem with this code .

```
<form method="post">
<p>
<iframe src="exampel.com" id="frame1" scrolling="yes" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<input name="b1" id="b1" onclick="return TextToFrame();" type="button" value="send to iframe" />

 <script type="text/javascript">
 function TextToFrame()
 {   
   var x = document.getElementById("frame1");
   x.contentDocument.getElementById("txtUsername").value = "897818930000";
   x.contentDocument.getElementsByid("btnLogin")[0].click();
   return;
 }
</script>
</p>
</form>
```

thanks

Comment: you can only access the document of an iframe if its on the same domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to get your log in form from iframe ? 
If you are doing this to get interactive log in form i recommend you to use this :

```
<form action="login.php" method="post" target="login-target" id = "loginform">
//inputs and sumbit button here
</form>
<iframe id="login-target" name="login-target" ></iframe>
```

this way your form will be submitted using iframe without refreshing and you can get result from iframe usig jquery or javascript

Answer (score 0):

You have an iFrame that displays content from a URL that has a different origin than the document the iFrame is on. Now when you try to access the DOM tree of that iFrame, this violates your browser's same origin policy: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy. There are several mitigation mechanisms around that. The best would probably be to have the iFrame content hosted on the origin.

Answer (score 0):

Owing to the same origin policy, you can only access the document of an iframe only if its on the same domain.

You may set-up the login page `http://46.4.83.151` from which you source the iframe to receive **additional parameters in query string** which are used to fill up the text box

`<iframe src="http://46.4.83.151?txtUsername=897818930000" id="frame1" scrolling="yes" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe>`

Similarly you can define another URL which when requested loads a page which has the button's `onclick` as its `onload`